# approach of|to doing something

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct when *approach* is followed by doing something?

> An efficient approach **of|to** learning is doing things that are interesting while lazing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the use you ask about only *to* is acceptable. This is easy to remember: the base meaning of *approach*, as either a noun or a verb, is *going nearer **to** something*, and this still holds in both literal uses and figurative ones like yours, where one approaches an objective or goal:

> The approach **to** the manor ran between ranks of ancient elms.
>   Interactive multimedia offers a new approach **to** learning.

When you are describing something other than the objective, however, other prepositions may be called for. *From* and *via* name the origin and 'path' of the approach, just as they do in literal uses:

> Our approach **from** a deconstructionist perspective reveals an alternative interpretation.
>   The approach **via** cost reduction will have a greater impact on the bottom line.

*Of* is used to name an approach's most important characteristic(s):

> Ford's approach **of** assigning each worker a single task, repeated over and over, greatly improved efficiency.